Blender Geometry Nodes 'Point Scale' node missing. Looking for an alternative
I'm following this teleportation effect in blender tutorial by Max Zhang 3D but it's a 3-year-old video, so his Blender version is also old.
I'm new to geometry nodes so I don't know if I'll be able to go into the technicalities of my doubt but from what I see is that around 2:40 in the tutorial he uses a node called 'Point Scale' which is missing in Blender 4.1.
I tried messing around with the nodes but nothing worked out.
I would really appreciate it if someone out there could spare their time to help me with this as I have a deadline to be met.

this is the screenshot from the tutorial.

this is my blender setup.

The point scale value has been integrated into the Instance on points node, so you can control the cubes size with a Geomtery > Read > Named Attribute, targeting at the attribute with the name of the vertex group ("a" in my example).

